# Subproject building in Gradle and intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Is possibility to build only non-root module in Gradle (intelliJ IDEA environment) ?

Structure of my project is like this:

```
javaprojects
|- api
|- common
|- app
```

I have 4 build.gradle - one for every module: **javaprojects**, **api**, **common** and **app**.
In case I build parent module - **javaprojects**, everything is ok.
When I try to build for example **api**, I get error:

> Task 'clean' not found in root project 'api'.

so plugin **java** is not visible. It is freaky, because my IDE (intelliJ IDEA) show me, that **'api'** build.gradle has task 'clean' (it should be inherited from root module).
Of course I could add

```
apply plugin : 'java'
```

to build.gradle in **api** module, but I don't want do this. 
I defined in parent **build.gradle**:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

and in **settings.gradle**:

```
rootProject.name = 'javaprojects'
includeFlat 'api'
includeFlat 'common'
includeFlat 'app'
```

Comment: What do you get as the result of `gradle tasks`?

Comment: The result of `gradle tasks` in `api` directory: `:tasks`. Then there are listed also _Build Setup tasks_ and _Help tasks_, bot I don't see `clean` task.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle clean task is inherent and doesn't need explicit declaration.

If your module doesn't have a configuration defined in itself for the project directory structure, Gradle goes ahead with default directory structure, which is `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`.

You've to define the sources directory in module itself.